# JSON code to Array - quotes and double quotes

Tags: php, json

I have a big JSON code - 2 801 278 characters. Now I want to create an array from this JSON code in my PHP script, but I can't because my script has quotes and double quotes and PHP return an error. Here is a simply code which do the same problem:

```
{"title":"Example string's with \"special\" characters"}
```

As you can see, when I paste this code in that way:

```
var_dump(json_decode('{"title":"Example string's with \"special\" characters"}', true));
```

I got an error because `'` is not escaped. When I try to change change `string's` for `string\'s`, I got:

> Recoverable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be
>   converted to string in...

How I should change this JSON code to correctly create an array?

Comment: Are you going to paste the JSON into a script or read it from a file?

Comment: I paste code into a PHP script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do one of two things.

1. Read JSON from a file. (Recommended)
2. Use [Heredoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

**Reading JSON from a File**

Have a file next to your PHP file that has the JSON and read it using `file_get_contents()`.

```php
<?php
  $json = file_get_contents("file.json");
  $array = json_decode($json, true);
?>
```

**Using Heredoc**

```php
<?php
  $json = <<<EOD
{"title":"Example string's with \"special\" characters"}
EOD;
  $array = json_decode($json, true);
?>
```

Demo: https://eval.in/1119967

Both the above methods yield the same output.

Comment: Work fine! Thanks!